# serialization and Deserialization in c#

Tags: c#

I am facing a problem while doing serialization & deserialization using c#. Basically i am using DataContractSerializer to serialize an object.

Here is my serialization code:

```
 var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ProjectSetup));
     string xmlString;
     using (var sw = new StringWriter())
         {
             using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(sw))
                 {
                  writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                  serializer.WriteObject(writer, DALProjectSetup);
                  writer.Flush();
                  xmlString = sw.ToString();
                 }
          }                
      System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ProjectSetup"] = xmlString;
```

This is working correctly but now I need help on how to deserialize the above.

Comment: Anil, if my code is working you could mark it as answer. If its not provide some additional info.

Comment: i tried on google and code like this for deserialization : string toDeserialise = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ProjectSetup"].ToString(); DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ProjectSetup)); MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toDeserialise)); obj = (ProjectSetup)dcs.ReadObject(ms);

Comment: and getting error :The get-only collection of type 'System.Collections.Hashtable' returned a null value.  The input stream contains collection items which cannot be added if the instance is null.  Consider initializing the collection either in the constructor of the the object or in the getter.

Comment: well my code is using StringReader, and its not in google, its in the answer on your question.

Answer (score 10):

Valentin's answer shows you how to deserialize.

Re your comment:

> i am getting this error: The get-only collection of type 'System.Collections.Hashtable' returned a null value. The input stream contains collection items which cannot be added if the instance is null.

(note `HashTable` would generally be worth avoiding, too)

That is because `DataContractSerializer` *does not run a constructor*, so if you have:

```
private readonly HashTable myData = new HashTable();
[DataMember]
public HashTable MyData { get { return myData; } }
```

or:

```
private readonly HashTable myData;
[DataMember]
public HashTable MyData { get { return myData; } }
public MyType() {
    myData = new HashTable();
}
```

then `myData` will always be `null` for deserialization. A few ideas:

First, try adding a private set; for example:

```
[DataMember]
public HashTable MyData { get; private set; }
public MyType() {
    MyData = new HashTable();
}
```

Otherwise, you could use a before-deserialization callback:

```
[OnDeserializing]
void OnSerializing(StreamingContext ctx) {
    myData = new HashTable();
}
private HashTable myData = new HashTable();
[DataMember]
public HashTable MyData { get { return myData; } }
```

Or: make the property more intelligent:

```
private HashTable myData;
[DataMember]
public HashTable MyData { get { return myData ?? (myData = new HashTable()); } }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking following could work?

```
string toDeserialise = yourValue;
using(StringReader sr = new StringReader(toDeserialize))
using(XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(sr))
{
   return (ProjectSetup)serializer.ReadObject(xmlReader);
}
```

Comment: i am getting this error: The get-only collection of type 'System.Collections.Hashtable' returned a null value.  The input stream contains collection items which cannot be added if the instance is null.  Consider initializing the collection either in the constructor of the the object or in the getter.

Comment: @Anil added an answer addressing that