# Getting error deserializing with DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, datacontractserializer

When I am deserializing my object back to it's original type my object is always `null`.

Here is my code:

```
ProjectSetup obj = new ProjectSetup();

if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ProjectSetup"] == null)
    setBookProjectSetup();

string toDeserialise = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.
    Session["ProjectSetup"].ToString();

DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ProjectSetup));
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toDeserialise));
obj = (ProjectSetup) dcs.ReadObject(ms, true);

return obj;
```

Comment: Did you see the answer I added here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397754/serialization-and-deserialization-in-c/7398981#7398981 - does that address the question?
Also: general tip: never way "error" - give the **exact, verbatim** error

Comment: btw; a `catch(Exception ex) {throw ex;}` does nothing good, and causes harm (it destroys the stack-trace) - avoid that.

Comment: How do you serialize the object?

Comment: The code is indeed incomplete.
@Marc +1, plus catching a general exception is good practice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that the call to `setBookProjectSetup` places an instance of `ProjectSetup` in the `HttpSessionState` with a key of `ProjectSetup`.

The issue here starts with this:

```
string toDeserialise = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.
    Session["ProjectSetup"].ToString();
```

You subsequently use the contents of the `toDeserialize` string as the source of the deserialization.

Unless you've overloaded [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) to return a byte stream that the [`DataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) would be able to deserialize (it's highly unlikely) chances are you are using the implementation of `ToString` on `Object`, which will just return the type's name.

Then, you are trying to deserialize that string into your object, which isn't going to work.

What you need to do is properly serialize your object into a byte array/[`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx), like so:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    // Create the serializer.
    var dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ProjectSetup));

    // Serialize to the stream.
    dcs.WriteObject(ms, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ProjectSetup"]);
```

At this point, the `MemoryStream` will be populated with a series of bytes representing your serialized object.  You can then get the object back using the same `MemoryStream`:

```
    // Reset the position of the stream so the read occurs in the right place.
    ms.Position = 0;

    // Read the object.
    var obj = (ProjectSetup) dcs.ReadObject(ms);
}
```